# How to count the same strings in multiple list in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary variable, in which have to count the same strings in multiple list inside a list

example:

```
df = {"123":{"grade":[["DESC",'12hwe'],["age",28],["DESC",'jbwdjb'],["score",76]]}}
```

I want to count the number of lists with "DESC" inside the list( for the above example,the count of "DESC" is 2)

```
for i in range(df["123"]["grade"]):
  print(count(df["123"]["grade"][i][0]=="DESC"))
```

Any suggestions would be much appriciated !

Comment: The function you want is `sum`.  `sum("DESC" in x for x in df["123"]["grade"])` == 2.

Comment: NameError ... on 12hwe and jbwdjb

Comment: Firstly, your 12hwe and jbwdjb should be in quotation marks, otherwise, you will receive a syntax error. 
Secondly, you need to put comma as following, ["age",28],["DESC","jbwdjb"], otherwise, you will receive a typeerror.

Answer (score 0):

your example data has a tuple in it , and I assume that if it is regular array so you can count it like that

```
df = { "123": {"grade": [["DESC", "12hwe"], ["age", 28],["DESC", "jbwdjb"], ["score", 76]]}}
listOfList = df["123"]["grade"]

splash = [i == "DESC" for x in listOfList for i in x]

print(sum(splash))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a very efficient solution but still leads to your desired output. I assumed it is just a simple case of counting the occurrence of `DESC` string:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
import re

df = {"123":{"grade":[["DESC",'12hwe'],["age",28],["DESC",'jbwdjb'],["score",76]]}}

# First we flatten your nested dictionaries
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df)

# Then we create a list out of the resulting data frame
lst = list(chain.from_iterable(df2['123.grade']))

# Now we count the number of occurrence in the resulting list
len(re.findall('DESC', str(lst)))

2
```

Since I have recently started using Python I would appreciate any hint to improve this solution.